how to send data through db9 connector in node js
I have an issue and is that I can not, or do not know how to send a data through serial port using db9 connector using nodejs with its serialport library.
I’m trying to create a simple api in which when making a request to my local ip can open the com port and send a data in hexadecimal, said data goes to a max-232 connected to the db9 port of my pc, I’m on windows 10, I don’t know how to see if the data I send is correct or if at least something is being sent.
I leave you my code:
import express from 'express'
import { SerialPort } from 'serialport'

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1902
const port = new SerialPort({
  path: 'COM1',
  baudRate: 9600,
  parity: 'none'
})

const writeOnPort = () => {
  if (port.isOpen) {
    port.write('0x43afc0', 'hex')
  } else {
    port.open()
    port.write('0x43afc0', 'hex')
  }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('This is the main page')
  writeOnPort()
})

app.get('/close', (req, res) => {
  res.send('This page close the port')
  port.close()
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server on port ${PORT}`)
})


